# What are these arrows on a schematic?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematic

I am trying to understand a schematic by Espressif for the ESP32 devkit v4.

There are 7 arrows on U1 (CP2102N-A01-GQFN28) and 1 on U3 (ESP32_WROVER(NC)).

Why U1 have a green rectangle?

Link to the full [schematic](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf).

[image: Expressif ESP32 Dev Kit v4 partial]
Image by [Expressif.](https://www.espressif.com)

Comment: the arrows seem to indicate inputs ... you can confirm this by checking the CP2102N datasheet  .... it is quite possible that the datasheet contains the green rectangle for some purpose

Answer (score 9):

The arrows mark the pins as inputs. What the idea of the green rectangle is, is unclear. But it has probably no electrical functionality.

Comment: i cannot understand on the schematic tho where are those inputs coming from.. since thats the full scematic it should be somewhere there..

Comment: @ChrisT, the red text labels are connections to all other points labeled the same. Typically, a simple label means "on the same sheet" while a label with a box around means "on any sheet", but these aren't absolutes, so there might be another sheet containing the serial port level converters and the USB port.

Answer (score 8):

The arrows have been explained (inputs to the microprocessor.)

The inputs come from another section of the schematic.  Here's a larger view:

[image]

The text flags on the microprocessor inputs connect to the flags of the same names in the lower left corner of the drawing.

From there, they go to pins on the connector:

[image]

The green rectangle seems to indicate a difference between the ESP32 WROOM and the ESP32 WROVER modules:

[image]

The name of the ESP32 WROVER module is in the same green color as the rectangle in the schematic.  I take that to mean that the circuitry in the green rectangle is present on the WROVER module but not the WROOM.

Comment: however DSR flag on U1 is defined as input but there's nowhere in the schematic DSR connected to

Comment: Then either DSR isn't connected, or there's an error in the diagram.  I couldn't find any further connection in the schematic for DSR.

Answer (score 5):

It's an OrCAD schematic. When you make a symbol with the pin type attribute set to 'input' it adds that arrow. Using the pin type attribute not only helps convey information, but is useful for design rules checking.

The green rectangle is just a graphic added by the designer, it has no electrical meaning. Perhaps they wished to indicate that the parts are laid out together, or have a specific purpose.